# Error when installing php-zip7.0

Tags: apt, server, mysql, php

Whenever I run `sudo apt-get install php-zip7.0` I get the following

```
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So, I tried installing the two packages using `sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server` but I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

[A user on the Ubuntu Forums had the same problem](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2325143&p=13495075#post13495075) and said these commands from [post #16 of this thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1763604&p=10853669#post10853669) solved the issue, it's worth a shot I guess:

```
sudo dpkg -P mysql-server mysql-server-5.7
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
dpkg -l | grep -i mysql
sudo rm -rvf /var/lib/mysql
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```